# Css not applied to canvas tag

Tags: html, css

Why is this style not being applied to the canvas in the codes below?

```css
canvas, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color: black;
};
body{ position: relative };
canvas{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left:0; right:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); z-index: 999
};
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
        <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the background color is not shown, since `canvas{...}` is not been applied (neither if i use `.canvas{...}`)

Comment: Add height 100% to html tag as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolons after the style blocks and it should work. Notice how the `body { position: relative; }` isn't applied either.

**So, corrected:**

```css
canvas, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color: black;
}

body { 
    position: relative;
}

canvas {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 999

}
```

Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes

Comment: Happens to everybody. I've made dumber.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is an element used for JS. As you have no JS that actually draw anything in there, it will stay black.

Also you have huge formatting mistakes. You have 2 different CSS styles that talk to the same elements. Also your CSS formatting with the tags is wrong,you made the `;` come after the closing tag, it has to be inside!

Also a `position: absolute;` with a top, bottom, left and right does not work! you either set it to top or bottom and/or left or right.

Comment: Note that the top/bottom/left/right are actually separated by semicolons, which is fine. I use one rule per line, but what's included above is technically 100% valid.

Comment: no, if you don't draw nothing inside a canvas, and you set the background color, the background color will be drawn; then, applying the same rule will just override the old value with the new one, there is no problem about that; the top-bottom-right-left is widely used ([see for example here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/top-right-bottom-left/#setting-opposite-sides)), the problem was only the `;` at the end of the blocks